# Git. Почему родителями считаются более поздние коммиты?

Tags: git, git-flow

Разбирался в основах Git и в главе, посвященной [основам слияния](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-Git-%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)  появился вопрос.

Почему родителями считаются более поздние коммиты, расположенные в "кроне" графа и стрелки идут к ним, а не от них?

Ведь по логике, они являются "слепками" с предыдущего состояния.

Например, используя эту картинку, объясняется слияние ветки hotfix в ветку master

> ветка, которую мы слили (*прим - hotfix), указывала на коммит, являющийся прямым родителем коммита, на котором мы сейчас находимся (**прим - master), Git просто сдвинул её указатель вперёд

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И из этого описания получается, что С4 является родителем С2, хотя дело обстоит ровно наоборот (С4 содержит parentId, который указывает на С2)

Comment: *Почему родителями считаются более поздние коммиты* -- стоп-стоп-стоп, где вы это углядели?

Comment: А, вижу. Подозреваю, что имеет место ошибка перевода. Сейчас посмотрю детальнее.

Comment: В [оригинале (под fig. 21)](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging) текст несколько отличается: "Because the commit `C4` pointed to by the branch `hotfix` you merged in was directly ahead of the commit `C2` you’re on, Git simply moves the pointer forward."

Comment: @D-side да, оригинал сильно отличается в этом абзаце. Интересно, почему переводчики указали именно такое описание. Ведь даже в других частях переведенных доков говорится, что более поздние коммиты содержат ссылку parentId на более ранние коммиты.

Comment: Только я не очень понимаю ваш вопрос про стрелочки. У вас там точно ничего не перепутано?

Comment: Наверно, человек просто привык, что стрелочки обычно рисуют от начала к концу, от предыдущего к следующему, от родителя к потомку. А тут наоборот. Меня это тоже путает

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Подозреваю, что тут имеет место ошибка перевода.

"Родительский коммит" это пометка внутри каждого коммита о том, какое состояние было до него, в формате коммит-хэша. Пометка необязательно одна. Может быть и ноль (для начального коммита) и больше одной (для слияния).

Как правило, родительский коммит делается **до** потомка, но реально время на структуру графа коммитов не влияет, только вышеописанные "пометки". Нарушение этого скорее экзотика, но возможно.

Касательно стрелочек сложилось два прямо противоположных стиля:

- Указывать их "вперёд", по ходу разработки, якобы так история выглядит понятнее и отражает последовательность разработки.
- Указывать их "назад", против хода разработки, т. к. коммиты технически сами указывают на родителей, а не наоборот, т. к. содержат в себе ссылки (коммит-хэши) на родителей.

Какого-то предпочитаемого нет. Разве что там, где повествуют об устройстве Git, предпочитают второй стиль, как лучше соответствующий реальному устройству Git, а не удобной абстрактной картине к головах разработчиков.

Comment: с направлением стрелочек в гитовых схемах все очень просто и очевидно - каждый объект коммита хранит внутри себя хеш коммита-родителя. Говоря языком программистов - указатель на предка. А это обозначается ровно так, как принято у программистов - стрелочкой.

Comment: @KoVadim я вроде бы это и написал, нет? Вариант 2.

Comment: я немножко развернул:) Честно, стрелки от родителя к детям видел только в ужасных неверных объяснениях.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ! он прояснил ситуацию

Answer (score 2):

Номера указывают на верный хронологический порядок. `C0` — это корень дерева, первый коммит. От него идут другие коммиты. Когда создается новый коммит, он получает указатель на текущий актуальный коммит, тот становится родителем нового коммита. Указатель — это строка из 40 символов хеша SHA-1.

Разумеется, каждый коммит может быть родителем скольки угодно других коммитов. В мерж-коммитах может быть два или более родителя — несколько строк с SHA-1.

Именно такой указатель изображается стрелочкой. По стрелочкам можно пройти до конца — корневого коммита. В редких специально созданных случаях корней может быть более одного — git позволяет сделать слияние двух несвязанных деревьев.